# How to send input value in angular5 to grails3?

Tags: grails, angular5, grails3

I can't find any tutorial in grails3 to get input value in textarea from angular5 or any frontend, because I want to comparing the value with my data in database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular app (client) would need to POST the data to the backend (server) grails part where your controller should handle the incoming request object and pass it around to any services, etc to do whatever it is you are trying to do. The angular side would need to be listening (i.e. subscribed to the post observable) for the answer from your grails app response and determine what to show the user.

Comment: something like this?
 
 login() {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8080/userController',this.dataUser)
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.dataUser = data;   
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

Comment: Yes. Basically you are making an XHR request to the back-end app (your grails app) and then getting the response and acting on it.